# Deadlock necessary conditions

Tags: operating-system

I read that the 4 conditions for deadlock prevention are necessary conditions and not sufficient.

The four necessary conditions are :-

1.Mutual exclusion.

2.Hold and wait.

3.No preemption.

4.Circular wait.

Here it is clearly mentioned that these conditions are only necessary but not sufficient. https://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring03/V22.0202-002/lecture-06.html

Can someone please tell me why are they not sufficient? I am not able to come up with an example where all the conditions satisfy but deadlock doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

Another situation is if the resources are ordered and the system requires the resources to be locked in that order.

Comment: But if resources are ordered and deadlock happens then circular wait condition is not satisfied right?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a situation in which all the conditions hold true but there are more than one instance of resource on which it holds true. Then, There won't be a deadlock.